# Give the cdf and pdf given that we select a point uniformly on an annulus

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Select uniformly a point from the annulus $\{(x,y):1\leq x^2+y^2\leq 4\}$. Let R be the distance to $(0,0)$. Give the cdf and pdf of R.

---

I know that the sample space of choosing a point would be the area of the annulus ($3\pi$) and I know the method of getting the pdf from the cdf or vice versa. I'm just not sure how to start; How would I represent the distance R from the point (x,y) and would this be the cdf or pdf?

Comment: Why delete part of the question when the answers address that part specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I represent the distance R from the point (X,Y) and would this be the cdf or pdf?

By definition of Euclidean Distance, $R=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$.

So immediately we know the support is $\{r: 1\leqslant r^2\leqslant 4\}$

Now, since the points are uniformly distributed: the pdf for $R$, at any point $r$ within that support, will be equal to the ratio of the circumference of a circle with radius $r$ to the area of the annulus.  Call this $f_R(r)$.

And the CDF will be the integral $\displaystyle F_R(r)=\int_1^r f_R(s)\mathrm d s$ .

Comment: Thanks. Why would it be the circumference of the circle, would it not be the area?

Comment: @Graham Kemp doesn't this give for $r=2$ which lies within that support, $\Bbb{P}(R=2)=\frac{4}{3}>1$? I interpretted the pdf for $R$ at any point within the support as $\frac{2\pi r}{3 \pi} = \frac{2r}{3}$

Comment: A Probability *Density* Function may have values exceeding one. It is *not* a probability mass. Also, yes , $f_R(r)=\dfrac{2r}{3}\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant r\leqslant 2}$.

Comment: It is the circumference because that is the derivative of the area of a circle with respect to the radius.  (Which is a hint to find the CDF without integration.)

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to find the CDF first (and then it is easy to find the PDF from there). Try to compute $P(R \le r)$ for any real number $r$. (This will be a ratio of areas.)